# How to do with Pydantic regex validation?

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm trying to write a validator with usage of Pydantic for following strings (examples):
`1.1.0, 3.5.6, 1.1.2`, etc..

I'm failing with following syntax:

```
install_component_version: constr(regex=r"^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]$")
install_component_version: constr(regex=r"^([0-9])+.([0-9])+.([0-9])$")
install_component_version: constr(regex=r"^([0-9])\.([0-9])\.([0-9])$")
```

Can anyone help me out what regex syntax should look like?

Comment: `r'^(\d+\.){2}\d+$'` should work?

Comment: Thanks for replay @SUTerliakov. Unfortunetly still getting error from precommit:

`Invalid type comment or annotation  [valid-type]
 note: Suggestion: use constr[...] instead of constr(...)`

Comment: ...how about you share what _"I'm failing"_ looks like? What code are you **executing**? What output are you expecting and what is the exact error message or wrong output you are getting? Is it really that hard to formulate a proper question with a full error message and a reproducible example?

Comment: @Maciej this should probably help you https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/156#issuecomment-614748288 or any other suggestion in that

Comment: so try something like `install_component_version: str = Field(regex=r"^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]$")`, the error is not related to regex, its related to type annotation, which you can get around using `Field` if I understand the issue correctly, the regex is for you to figure out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are facing is due to type annotation.

As per https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/156 this is not yet fixed, you can try using `pydantic.Field` and then pass the `regex` argument there [like so](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/156#issuecomment-614748288)

`install_component_version: str = Field(regex=r"^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]$")`

This way you get the regex validation and type checking.

PS: This is not a 100% alternative to `constr` but if all you want is regex validation, the above alternative works and makes mypy happy.

As mentioned in the comments, if using Pydantic V2, `regex` is replaced with `pattern`.

`install_component_version: str = Field(pattern=r"^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]$")`

Comment: Is there any way to create a list of regex? I need that because I need to validate a list of regex. I have ```componend = list(str) = Field(regex = list(regex_vals)``` but I am getting an error mentioning that I can use list when using the regex arg. Is there anyway to turn it around like that? Thanks!

Comment: @Danny I will have to check, but your expected is output is the string should match all the regexes in the list?

Comment: Yes, but it would be nice to return null or false if a regex doesn't match the regexes in the list. However, if that is not possible at this point, it is not necessary

Comment: @Danny : How about chaining the regexes / using alternative types? I.e. `pattern="^(regex1)|(regex2)|....$"` or `componend: list[ constr(pattern=regex1) | constr(pattern=regex2) ]`

Comment: for new comers, `regex` argument is removed, use `pattern` instead.

Answer (score 3):

On newer versions of pydantic use `pattern` instead of `regex`:
Example:

```py
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    """
    Model of my class
    """

    my_field: str = Field(min_length=10, max_length=10, pattern=r"[A-Z]\d{9}")
```